# jQuery.HotKeys keybinding while input is focused

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-hotkeys

I am using jquery.hotkeys for implementing keyboard shortcuts.

My code:

```
$(document).bind('keydown', 'Ctrl+f', function () {
        $('#myid').focus();
        return false;
    });
```

This works fine. But if any input is in focus, the keystroke defaults to the browser original (in this case find). If I click outside the input box, intended function is called by jquery.hotkeys.

What should I do if I want to get the uniform behaviour whether input is focused or not?

Comment: Do all of your hotkeys start with ctrl?

Comment: @Kramb Yes, unfortunately :-(

Answer (score 2):

You can give this a shot:

```
$(document).bind('keydown', function(e) {
    if (e.ctrlKey && e.which == 70) {
        $('#myid').focus();
        return false;
    }
});
```

The problem is, it's not using the plugin. So feel free to NOT mark this the answer even if it works for you as it does not answer the initial question IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

Refer docs: https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys#hotkeys-within-inputs

> Hotkeys aren't tracked if the user is focused within an input element
>   or any element that has contenteditable="true" unless you bind the
>   hotkey directly to the element. This helps to avoid conflict with
>   normal user typing. If you don't want this, you can change the
>   booleans of the following to suit:
>
> jQuery.hotkeys.options.filterInputAcceptingElements
>   jQuery.hotkeys.options.filterContentEditable
>   jQuery.hotkeys.options.filterTextInputs (deprecated, will be removed
>   in a later version)

Comment: I saw these options but either they do not work or I don't know their syntax (there are some jQuery basics that I struggle with). I assume that is should be: `jQuery.hotkeys.options.filterInputAcceptingElements = false;` but that doesn't work. Is it correct?